# ssh from Linux to Windows returns special characters

Tags: windows, openssh

ssh from Linux to Windows returns special characters

[2J[1;1H[0;39;24;27;37;40mWindows PowerShell
[2;1HCopyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

[4;1HPS C:\Users\Administrator>                                                      [4;4HC:\Users\Administrator>                                                      [4;26H>                                                      [4;28H[4;28H[4;28He                                                    [4;29H[4;29Hx                                                   [4;30H[4;30H[4;30Hi                                                  [4;31H[4;31Ht                                                 [4;32H[4;32H

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [su].

Answer (score 0):

If you have openssh installed on the Windows system, you just need to set the TERM environment variable on your Linux system, before connecting.

```
export TERM=xterm
```

https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/TTY-PTY-support-in-Windows-OpenSSH